# Determining threshold for lock escalation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with around 2.5 millions records and will be updating around 700k of them and want to update these while still allowing other users to see the data. My update statement looks something like this:

```
UPDATE A WITH (UPDLOCK,ROWLOCK)
SET A.field = B.field
FROM Table_1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.id = B.id WHERE A.field IS NULL
AND B.field IS NOT NULL
```

I was wondering if there was any way to work out at what point sql server will escalate a lock placed on an update statement (as I don't want the whole table to be locked)?

I don't have permissions to run a server trace to see how the locks are being applied, so is there any other way of knowing at what point the lock will be escalated to cover the whole table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx) once the statement has acquired 5,000 row or page level locks on a single instance of an object an attempt is made to escalate the locks. If this attempt fails because another transaction has a conflicting lock then it will try again after every additional 1,250 locks are acquired.

I'm not sure if you can actually take these figures as gospel or not or whether there are a few more subtleties than that (I guess you could always hit the memory limit for the instance at any number of locks)

Comment: Would that imply that if you kept an open transaction that's locking one row exclusively (that you know you're massive update isn't going to try to access) that SQL Server would carry on with just page locks (thus avoiding the table lock the OP is concerned about).

Comment: @Damien - Yes. It will never be able to take an exclusive table lock if another transaction already has an `IX` lock on the table. I think at some point it could just abandon the whole process though if the memory it was using for locks got too much.

Comment: Would locking one row exclusively to force page / row locks rather than table locks would ever be a good idea?

Comment: I guess like all areas where you take away management from SQL server only if you have determined the default behaviour is not appropriate for your workload and have researched the alternatives (e.g. snapshot isolation) and down sides.

Comment: @Damien: `SQL Server` will attempt to escalate the lock and this will block the `UPDATE` transaction since this escalation would conflict with the row lock held by the single-row-locking transaction. While waiting, it will still hold the exclusive row-level locks acquired to the moment.

Comment: @Quassnoi - But from the BOL link if the escalation attempt fails it will just go back to taking `rowlocks` and try again after another 1,250 row locks are taken or the memory requirements go beyond some threshold and it rolls back  it won't be blocked permanently AFAIK?

Comment: @Martin: I was talking about the situation when there is no more memory available for the new locks, but you are right, it will generate an error in this case.

Comment: And of course you would need to take care that the row locked by the other transaction wasn't one that would be affected by the `update`!

Answer (score 4):

As @Martin states, 5000 is the number BOL gives, however i've seen the actual number vary in production.

You have two options:

1) Batch your updates and try to keep the batchsize under 5000

2) Disable lock escalation (becareful) via:

- *ALTER TABLE (sql2k8)
- *Trace Flags 1211/1224

  ([SQL Server 2008: Lock escalation changes](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/SQL-Server-2008-Lock-escalation-changes.aspx))
- By other locking tricks

Here's a method you can use to systematically determine your threshold. (Assuming you have VIEW SERVER STATE permissions).

```
DECLARE @BatchSize int;
SET @BatchSize = <Vary this number until you see a table lock taken>;

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE TOP(@BatchSize) A WITH (UPDLOCK,ROWLOCK)
SET A.field = B.field
FROM Table_1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.field IS NULL
AND B.field IS NOT NULL


SELECT
    * 
FROM
    sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE
    [request_session_id] = @@spid


ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Very useful! This confirms what @Martin said above, it changes the lock to table level once 5000 locks have been created. How would I go about batching the update into blocks of 5000 without needing to overwrite continually?

Comment: Wrap a while loop around your update and break if @@rowcount < @BatchSize.  Unless i'm reading your query wrong, the while loop will exit when you are done populating all of table_1's field column has data.

Answer (score 2):

`ROWLOCK` hint does not prevent lock escalation, it just informs the server that it should not assume initial locking level and start from rows.

Row locks then may be promoted to a table lock.

To make the table data available for reading during the update, use `SNAPSHOT` transaction isolation level.

Comment: When using Snapshot isolation level would I also need the rowlock hint or would (given that I am updating many more than 5k rows) this not have any effect?

Comment: @Davin: `SNAPSHOT` isolation queries do not request read locks at all. Note that you should make the reading transactions `SNAPSHOT` isolated, not the writing one.

Comment: @Quassnoi - the main issue I have is that a front end application reads the data (where isolation levels / locks cannot be changed) and so what I need is to only lock data on a row-by-row basis as it is being updated so that users can still view the data (without locking the whole table) – is this possible?

Comment: What isolation level are they on at the moment? If `read committed` changing to `read committed snapshot` would require zero code changes (though it does have implications on `tempdb` you should research first)

Comment: @Davin: adding to @Martin's comment: set `READ_COMMITTED_SHAPSHOT = ON` to enable snapshot locking behavior for `READ COMMITTED` transactions. Setting this variable will make `SQL Server` to keep the overwritten data in `tempdb` in addition to storing it in the transaction logs.

Comment: @Martin it's currently set to read committed and I think this is how it's going to have to stay. As much as possible I was hoping to update in complete isolation and only lock the data when committing the transaction!