# How to efficiently use LOCK_ESCALATION in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, locking, deadlock

I'm currently having troubles with frequent deadlocks with a specific user table in SQL Server 2008. Here are some facts about this particular table:

1. Has a large amount of rows (1 to 2 million)
2. All the indexes used on this table only have the **"use row lock"** ticked in their options
           ***Edit: There is only one index on the table which is its primary Key***
3. rows are frequently updated by multiple transactions but are unique (e.g. probably a thousand or more update statements are executed to different unique rows every hour)
4. the table does not use partitions.

Upon checking the table on `sys.tables`, I found that the `lock_escalation` is set to `TABLE`

I'm very tempted to turn the lock_escalation for this table to `DISABLE` but I'm not really sure what side effect this would incur. From What I understand, using `DISABLE` will minimize escalating locks from `TABLE` level which if combined with the row lock settings of the indexes should theoretically minimize the deadlocks I am encountering..

From what I have read in [Determining threshold for lock escalation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679222/determining-threshold-for-lock-escalation) it seems that locking automatically escalates when a single transaction fetches 5000 rows..

What does a single transaction mean in this sense? A single session/connection getting 5000 rows thru individual update/select statements?

Or is it a single sql update/select statement that fetches 5000 or more rows?

Any insight is appreciated, btw, n00b DBA here

Thanks

Comment: A single connection/transaction, that **UPDATES** (or inserts) 5000 rows or more will cause lock escalation. And yes - you *can* turn it off - but I don't think that would be a very good idea - if you disable lock escalation, you're putting **a lot more** strain and work onto the SQL Server lock manager - while it *might* prevent table lock, it will **bring down performance** for your statements significantly. After all: there is a **good reason** why SQL Server escalates the locks after it reaches 5000 per connection ....

Comment: post a [deadlock graph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx) (the XML, not the picture of it!). I recommend reverting the settings to default (enable page locks). Don't play with napalm. Most likely you're missing some indexes.

Comment: I dont think your deadlocks are related to tables locks. They are essentially different concepts. Like Remus said dont play with Napalm there is a reason these setting are in there. However like I mentioned a deadlock and a table lock is different concepts all together.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I see your point about the indexes since after a closer look into my particular table, it seems that there are no other indexes besides the primary key. Due to real life constraints (production server *cough) I can't use the profiler at the moment (since the people who actually owns the server is afraid of a possible slowdown due to the profiler) but will try to get the deadlock graph as soon as I can. For the meantime, is there any DMVs i can use for detecting issues like what I'm having now? Thanks

Comment: @Namphibian can you elaborate what you meant by table lock being different from a deadlock? I know that the concept are different, I'm just wondering if a table lock can possibly cause a deadlock. Thanks

Comment: @marc_s I understand what you're trying to say and honestly, I am  trying to balance statement performance with minimizing locks.

Comment: [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx): large number of `user_scans` vs. low number of `user_seeks` will indicate missing indexes.

Comment: @RemusRusanu sorry for asking but aren't the rows in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats indicates the indexes that already exists? Does that mean that if I have records there with large_scans vs. user_seeks, then I need to add more indexes to that particular object_id/table? Thanks

Comment: The rows int he DMV are one per rowset, and a rowset could be a Heap or a BTree , and the BTree could be a clustered or a non-clustered index. So your table will always have at least one row there. If you're scanning the clustered index is indication that you probably need a non-clustered index to use a more efficient seek. Scans are acceptable only for analytic queries that need to aggregate results for the entire table anyway.

Comment: I think I can see what you mean. My table does indeed have a large number of user_scans vs. a low number of user_seeks. Will try to implement new indexes once they have been approved by my supervisor. Thanks

Comment: @Avias a deadlock can be caused by row locks and page locks. Lets say transaction A has a lock on row 1 and needs to lock row 2 to complete the transaction but transaction B has locked row 2 and needs to lock row 1 to complete the transaction you have a deadlock. These locks could be row locks, page locks however a exclusive table lock will stop anything from accessing the table so if transaction A locked the table then transaction B would not be able to start. Essentially a table lock is a lock on one resource the table. Row locks and page locks normally cause deadlocks.

Comment: @Namphibian thats exactly what Im trying to prevent. By reducing the locks to row level, I'm trying to avoid deadlocks even if it will cost a bit more resource. Again as much as possible Im trying to balance performance with the risk of deadlocks

Comment: @Avias row locks and page locks are the primary candidates for deadlocks not table locks. Maybe I did not make it clear but if a transaction issues a table lock no other transaction will be able to even start till lock is cleared thus deadlocks cannot occur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LOCK Escalation triggers when a statement holds more than 5000 locks on a SINGLE object. A statement holding 3000 locks each on two different indexes of the same table will not trigger escalation.

When a lock escalation is attempted and a conflicting lock exists on the object, the attempt is aborted and retried after another 1250 locks (held, not acquired)

So if your updates are performed on individual rows and you have a supporting index on the column, then lock escalation is not your issue.

You will be able to verify this using the Locks-> lock escalation event from profiler.

I suggest you capture the deadlock trace to identify the actual cause of the deadlock.

Comment: 11/22/2012 16:04:28,spid8s,Unknown,Wait-for graph
11/22/2012 16:04:28,spid8s,Unknown,Deadlock encountered .... Printing deadlock information
11/22/2012 16:04:23,spid27s,Unknown,waiter id=process1b8154988
11/22/2012 16:04:23,spid27s,Unknown,waiter-list
11/22/2012 16:04:23,spid27s,Unknown,owner id=process1c962b048
11/22/2012 16:04:23,spid27s,Unknown,owner id=process23a98b948
11/22/2012 16:04:23,spid27s,Unknown,owner id=process172ecfdc8
11/22/2012 16:04:23,spid27s,Unknown,owner id=process307993048
11/22/2012 16:04:23,spid27s,Unknown,owner id=process228b81288

Comment: Manage to get some old trace logs a few weeks ago (posted above this post), what the hell am I looking at here? Honestly I have little to no idea what I'm looking at

Comment: You will need to provide the complete trace data for the deadlock. You can paste it to pastebin and share the link.

Also note you may be able to capture deadlock graph after the fact by using the script mentioned in http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/getting-historical-deadlock-info-using-extended-events.aspx

Comment: @RojiPThomas - Regarding that script in Paul Randal's post sometimes the query plan can be quite catastrophic. [See the answers to my question here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30947)

Answer (score 1):

I found this article after a quick Google of disabling table lock escalation. Although not a real answer for the OP I think it is still relevant for one off scripts and note worthy here. There's a nice little trick you can do to temporarily disable table lock escalation.
Open another connection and issue something like.

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT * FROM mytable (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE 1=0
WAITFOR DELAY '1:00:00'
COMMIT TRAN
```

as

> Lock escalation cannot occur if a different SPID is currently holding
>   an incompatible table lock.

from [microsoft kb](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323630)